# Highcharts Label redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am working off [this JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/22zon8c6/) which shows how to add a label to a point in a chart. This works fine for fixing a position for the label in the case of the chart not being responsive. Change the width of the fiddle and the label sits in the original position. I want the label to stay on top of the last column.

I have tried using `load` and `redraw` events and I am close, but I need to destroy the label before creating a new one.

```
events: {
    load: function () {
        var point = this.series[0].points[2];
        this.renderer.label(
                '<div class="text-center">GOAL TO REACH</div>', 270, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + this.plotLeft, point.plotY + this.plotTop
        )
        .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
        .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 6
        })
        .add();
    },
    redraw: function() {
        var point = this.series[0].points[2];
        this.renderer.label(
                '<div class="text-center">GOAL TO REACH</div>', 270, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + this.plotLeft, point.plotY + this.plotTop
        )
        .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
        .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 6
        })
        .add();
    }
 }
```

I want the label to follow the point when the chart's width is changed.

I tried using a tooltip, but has problems disabling it from the first two columns. I can redraw the tooltip ok, but could not disable it from all other columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22zon8c6/11/)

I added a variable to the global scope `var theLabel;`

Then on chart initial draw, set `theLabel = chart.renderer.label(...)`

Then

```
redraw: function() {
    theLabel.destroy();
        point = this.series[0].points[2];
        theLabel = this.renderer.label('<div class="text-center">Reach 10 active subscriptions<br/>and enjoy a one year FREE membership!</div>', this.plotWidth - 200, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + this.plotLeft, point.plotY + this.plotTop)
    .css({
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    })
    .attr({fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
      padding: 8,
      r: 5,
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();
}
```

Note that in `redraw:`:

1. I call `theLabel.destroy()` to remove the original label
2. I changed `chart` to `this`
3. Instead of plotting it at `x = 270` I plot it at `this.plotWidth - 200` to get it more-or-less on the right hand side of the plot with the chevron always pointing to the red bar.

Hope this works for you